# Laravel Livewire checkbox checked on edit page

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm facing an issue with checking the checkbox on the edit page using Livewire. I've tried many ways but still not able to check the old selected value

**View Code:**

```
<table id="branches" class="table table-bordered table-sm" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th width="10%">

          </th>
          <th>Branch ID</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      @foreach ($propertiesOptions as $key => $property)
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <input class="branchCheckbox" 
                  type="checkbox" 
                  wire:model="propertyIds.{{$property->id}}" 
                  value="{{$property->id}}" @if(in_array($property->id,$propertyIds)) checked @endif>
              </td>
            <td>{{$property->id}}</td>
         </tr>
     @endforeach
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**Backend Code:**

````
public $propertyIds, $propertiesOptions;
public function mount($record)
    {
        $this->propertiesOptions = Properties::where('merchant_id',$record->id)->get()
        $this->propertyIds = $record->properties->pluck('property_id')->toArray();

    }```
````

Comment: I updated my answear. take a look.

Comment: hey, thank you for answering the question. However I tried this way but it didn't work

Comment: but my problem got solved by reading this answer https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/livewire-checkbox-not-checked-on-render

Comment: Hey @Humza Faqi ! Good to konw. It means: `<input class="branchCheckbox" type="checkbox" wire:model="propertyIds.{{$property->id}}"  value="{{$property->id}}">` without condition and livewire does the rest.

Answer (score 1):

```
`<table id="branches" class="table table-bordered table-sm" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th width="10%">

          </th>
          <th>Branch ID</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      @foreach ($propertiesOptions as $key => $property)
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <input class="branchCheckbox" 
                  type="checkbox" 
                  wire:model="propertyIds" 
                  value="{{$property->id}}" >
              </td>
            <td>{{$property->id}}</td>
         </tr>
     @endforeach
 </tbody>
</table>`
```

**BACKEND**

```
public $propertyIds, $propertiesOptions;
public function mount($record)
    {
        $this->propertiesOptions = Properties::where('merchant_id',$record->id)->get()
        $this->propertyIds = $record->properties->pluck('property_id')->toArray();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**updated**
And can you check if this correct?  `wire:model="propertyIds.{{$property->id}}"`? Try to delete the wire:model .

```
<input class="branchCheckbox" type="checkbox" 
  value="{{$property->id}}" 
  @if(in_array($property->id,$propertyIds)) checked @endif>
```